# How do you use an oscilloscope to detect radio waves intercepted by a transistor radio?

Tags: rf, oscilloscope

I'm planning to conduct an experiment involving electromagnetic waves (specifically radio waves) and the resistance imposed on them by different materials. It is my understanding that in order to do so, I should connect the transistor radio picking up the radio waves to an oscilloscope in order to measure the signal strength. However, I'm not sure how I would do this.

Though, I may be going about this all wrong, so any additional information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What frequencies are you interested in? "Radio waves" cover quite a broad range of the EM spectrum. Depending on the frequency/wavelength it might be difficult to put enough material into the line of propagation.

Comment: One of the problems with using a 'radio' is that they contain an agc (automatic gain control) circuit  so you won't get a reading proportional to attenuation. Google field strength meter

Comment: Why do you think you need an oscilloscope? You probably don't need to see then waveform or phase of the signal (and there could be many signals). Maybe a receiver with signal strength indicator is enough.

Comment: @Curd I was thinking of using a local radio station as a source, though I may be able to use a transmitter. Also, I want to gather as much data as possible and I'm not sure the radio will have the capability to measure signal strength anyway.

Comment: @JIm Dearden I think AGCs are absent from some (normally less sophisticated) transistor receivers.

Comment: @KrisWalker Yes but I don't know which radio the OP is using and even cheap radios have AGCs these days. I raised it to make the OP aware of this particular problem. Its easy enough to built a field strength meter for just about any frequency band and it would make a better tool for experiment/measurement purposes than a radio (of unknown circuitry).

Comment: @Kris Walker: but what **frequency** is the local radio station using? Is it a FM Station (then it's ca. 100MHz) or is it an AM Station? If it is the latter then the only way to test various materials is to have the material already there (e.g. mountain) and move the Receiver behind it or not.

Comment: @JImDearden Hi, it's me, the OP :) 

Yeah, I see what you mean. If I can acquire an FSM, I'll be sure to use it, but it isn't a certainty.

Comment: @Curd They are FM and range between 95MHz and 99MHz. A specific example would be 98.7MHz.

Comment: Get an SDR, it does this all digitally

Answer (score 2):

I would be less concerned with using the resistance of different materials for the reason of showing the power level of RF.  You could build a simple crystal radio with a tank circuit to show resonance which is how you would receive the power of a radio wave to begin with.   You could get creative and make a simple crystal radio  where you replace the diode with a transistor, then use a second tank circuit to tune in a close by, strong station to bias the transistor.  This will show the power of an RF signal.  You would naturally do this in the broadcast band.